# IBAN Regex to include spaces and dash

Tags: regex, iban

I'm trying to create a regex that would allow/register a IBAN number even if it includes dashes or spaces.

EX. 
Greece IBAN #

> `GR1601101250000000012300695`

Greece IBAN Regex

```
GR\d{2}\d{4}\d{3}\w\w{4}\w{4}\w{4}\w{3}
```

I want to combine these three(3) regexes into one(1) regex:

`GR\d{2} \d{4} \d{3}\w \w{4} \w{4} \w{4} \w{3}` (spaces)

`GR\d{2}\d{4}\d{3}\w\w{4}\w{4}\w{4}\w{3}` (no spcaes, no dashes)

`GR\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{3}\w-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{3}` (dashes)

Is this possible?

Any help that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If this is for Javascript, Netmage backref pattern would also work [but without named capturing group (see demo)](https://regex101.com/r/ztr0CD/1). Always important to specify regex flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you are in, you might be able to do something more sophisticated, but the easiest way is to just use alternation:

```
GR\d{2}( \d{4} \d{3}\w \w{4} \w{4} \w{4} \w{3}|\d{7}\w{16}|-\d{4}-\d{3}\w-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{3})
```

For example, with Perl or C# style regex you can remember and reference a match:

```
GR\d{2}(?<sep>[ -]?)\d{4}\k<sep>\d{3}\w\k<sep>\w{4}\k<sep>\w{4}\k<sep>\w{4}\k<sep>\w{3}
```

Comment: THanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your regex matches with "GR1601101250000000012300695" but not "GR 16 0110 125 0 0000 0001 2300 695" or "GR-16-0110-125-0-0000-0001-2300-695". I'm trying to discover IBAN numbers whether they have no spaces, spaces, dashes, or even a combination.

Comment: @NetMage looks like the backref pattern has little problem, the capture should be [after `GR` and one is missing between `\d{3}\w`](https://regex101.com/r/ztr0CD/2)

Comment: Actually, the standard says separators occur every four characters. Look at the original question again.

Comment: Hello again! Sorry for the delay for the delay in response. Bobble bubble, your regex does work, but I'm not sure the application I'm using can "digest" the k<sep> reference. Is it possible to get the same type of output with something to this: 
GR\d{2}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{3}[ -.]\w[ -.]\w{4}[ -.]\w{4}[ -.]\w{4}[ -.]\w{3}? Thanks!

Comment: That will also accept strings with mixed separaters (e.g. GR12-3456.1234 abcd...) and I think you have an extra [] between `\d{3}` and `\w`. What language/regex system are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm going for. I work in security and I'm trying to identify IBAN's in our environment and I want a consolidated regex, that is easily understood (for management), and is also adaptable. There is no language or sytem. I'll be uploading the regexes (regexi?) into an application. I put this (https://regex101.com/r/5COw3A/1) together last night based on the examples and feedback, and it seems to provide what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help, it is really appreciated!